# How is this fractal produced?

Tags: fractals, collatz-conjecture

[image]

It is stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Iterating_on_real_or_complex_numbers):

> Iterating the above optimized map $$f(z)=\frac{1}{4}(1 + 4z - (1 + 2z)\cos(\pi z))$$in the complex plane produces the
>   Collatz fractal.
>
> The point of view of iteration on the real line was investigated by
>   Chamberland (1996),[23] and on the complex plane by Letherman,
>   Schleicher, and Wood (1999).

However, in the 2 mentioned publications I did not find this image. I would like to know which start value $x_0$ created this image.

Am I correct, that this image is simply a visualization of the sequence $(f^n(x_o))_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ where the black parts show where the sequence remained for a long time? Does this sequence also end in a finite orbit?

Comment: why the collatz tag?

Comment: @Arjang if you restrict the function $f$ on the natural numbers you get the collatz function

Comment: Usually in these images, black points corresponds to convergent starting values while pixels are colored according to some measurement of how quickly divergence occurs. I think Wikipedia on Mandelbrot talks about ways of doing this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The start value $x_0$ is determined by the coordinates of each pixel.  Pixels are coloured acccording to how quickly the orbit for that pixel diverges (escape time colouring).  Black pixels remained bounded within the iteration limit.  I wrote a small GLSL implementation as demonstration: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Ms3XDn (it could be improved with smooth colouring, and user interface for moving around/zooming)

Here is a screenshot of the shadertoy with center (2.66, 0) and size 0.5 units:

[image: Collatz fractal 1]

And here's one with center (0, 0) and size 4 units:

[image: Collatz fractal 2]

Comment: Nice! THis is actually reproducing the image :D. Where is the origin (x,y)=(0,0) in your image?

Comment: @Adam the center of the image is around (2.5, 0) (but not exactly, would have to take into account the aspect ratio of the image more appropriately..)

Comment: Thank you. Could you also state the width of the picture? Is the length like 10000 or more like 10 units?

Comment: I second @adam 's last comment: I'd like to see the places,where the known cycles in the positive and the negative numbers are. *(Unfortunately the link doesn't work for me, something like WebGL is missing at my system)*

Comment: I added a couple of screenshots with location information.

Comment: thank you. What exactly do you mean when you say it has center (2.66,0) with size unit 0.5? Does it mean, then the total image is on the x-intervall [2.66-0.5,2.66+0.5] ? If not, I would be interested on the x-intervall $[x_1,x_2]$ and if possible the y-intervall $[y_1,y_2]$ where the image is located at.

Comment: @Adam I mean it's from $(x,y)=(2.66-a,-0.25)$ (bottom left) to $(2.66+a,0.25)$ (top right) where $a$ is determined by the pixels being square.