# Does anyone know something about this graph?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, parametric

First of all I whould like to appologize to the administrators and general public of this community for the vagueness of the title and content of my question. It's hard to describe something in mathematics when you have no idea how it's called or even the field it belongs to. If their is a way to make it somewhat relevant please tell me and I'll edit it. I will defenetly change the title when I get a satisfactory answer about the nature of the equation in question.

Years ago I had an application in my Windows Mobile 6.1 phone, called SpaceTime. That pretty powerful app had some demo equations and one of the was producing a graph like the one below:

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6CBa.jpg)

I drew that image from memory using CorelDraw. My old phone had been through some formats and has "died" a long time ago making it impossible to retrieve any information.

I'am very sure I remember the following characteristics correctly:

1. It was symmetric in both axis
2. The "bubbles" seemed to ascend like a lava lamb adding to the "stem's" length and accumulate in number above it as you progressed to the x or x'.

Does anyone know :
the parametric equation which can produce similar graphs ?
The name of the family of equations than can produce such graphs ?
The scientific field that benefits from it ?

I've been searching for this interesting graph for a long time and it's realy itching my brain not beeing able to find it anywhere...

Comment: Some images that look vaguely similar, but not identical https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1708799/how-is-this-fractal-produced, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2429991/115115

Comment: oh, no, it had nothing to do with fractals. the graph was very smooth. It's equation was realy complex making heavy use of sin() or cos() and floating numbers with many decimal points as factors.